# Regex to check if '-' or '+' are at start and end

Tags: .net, regex

I am  trying to make a regex which could check if the string matches the pattern `-*0001-`

Either the first character or the last character of the string can be a `+` or a `-`. There is an optional `*` at the start of the string, (after the `+` or `-`), and after that, we disallow special characters. There needs to be at least one character other than the `+`,`-`, and optional `*`.

The correct match would be

1. `-cccccc`
2. `cccccc-`
3. `+ccccc`
4. `ccccc+`
5. `+*cccc`
6. `*cccc+`

An incorrect match would be

1. `-cc*c`
2. `*-`
3. `+`
4. `+-`

The regex that I have so far is quite close but not close enough:

```
^([\+\-]?)(\*?)([a-z0-9]*)([\+\-]?)(\1\4)$
```

Comment: What about `ccccc`, `-ccccc-`, or `+ccccc-`?

Comment: What are the real requirements? It has to start OR end with + or -, and can have *any* or *no* characters in-between? So the following would match: `+` `-` `+       -`

Comment: what about `+`, `-`, `++`, `--`, `+\t\t`, `-\n`?

Comment: By the way: the regex you have posted is very complex... what exactly does it try to communicate? I'm not sure it is quite as close as you think - it matches text like `"+*523-+-"`...

Comment: @Kobi I used your answer thanks i slightly altered it since I noticed after posting that I had forgot to mention something `^(?:[+-]\*?\w+|\*?\w+[+-]|\*?\w+)$`

Comment: @Kobi Finalized your answer as `^(?:(?<UOMPrefix>[+-])(?<BCPrefix>\*?)(?<BarCode>\w+)|(?<BCPrefix>\*?)(?<BarCode>\w+)(?<UOMPrefix>[+-])|(?<BCPrefix>\*?)(?<BarCode>\w+))$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit should go to Kobi but for some reason he has removed his answer. I have editted it a bit

the final answer is

`^(?:(?<UOMPrefix>[+-])(?<BCPrefix>\*?)(?<BarCode>\w+)|(?<BCPrefix>\*?)(?<BarCode>\w+)(?<UOMPrefix>[+-])|(?<BCPrefix>\*?)(?<BarCode>\w+))$`

This takes into consideration Optional(+-)Optional(*)(characters)Optional(+-)

Comment: if you want to disallow special characters other than the initial `*`, then use `\w` instead of `\s`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something simpler, like this?

**Regex 1:** `([+-]\S+)|(\S+[+-])`

That would match any string that either started with `+`,`-` or ended with `+`,`-` (or both).
It doesn't check to see there's only one `+` or `-`, and it doesn't match `+` or `-` by itself or with any whitespace.

This matches `-ccc`, `+ccc`, `ccc-`, `ccc+`, `+ccc+`, `-ccc+`, `+++++`, `++`, but not `+` and not `+\t\t`

To not allow the last character to be `+` or `-` if the first character is `+` or `-`, and vice versa (string doesn't both start and end with `+` or `-`), you wanna do something like

**Regex 2:** `([+-]\S*[^+\-\s])|([^+\-\s]\S*[+-])`

This does not match `-ccc+` or `++` or `+++++` but it does match `+++++a`.

To not match any `+` or `-` in the interior of your class, you need to do

**Regex 3:** `([+-][^+\-\s]+)|([^+\-\s]+[+-])`

Which does not match `++++a`

**Edit**: Forgot to escape the `-` in the character class.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work in .Net just tried it in regex buddy

Comment: Your regexes depend on the particular regex engine. I know many engines that don't see the first `]` as an end to the set, because of the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your attempt or the other answer is so complicated.

This will do what the title asks:  `^([+-].*|.*[+-])$`

Is there more that you're not telling us?

Comment: Why? What else is there? Edit your question to specify more requirements than the title contains. This regex matches all your test cases. Perhaps give some examples of non-matching input

Comment: Did you bother to see what it is supposed to match

Comment: @Enzero In that case, your question is not clear enough. You say "for example "-*0001-", but you don't say what it is supposed to match precisely.

Comment: Edited: This regex *now* matches all your test cases. You have not specified a min/max langth, or what chars may appear in the middle. Perhaps give some examples of non-matching input.

Comment: I think he's trying to do partial string matches and hasn't told us yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants to match when both the first and last positions have the same character, which can be - or +, e.g. `-aaa-` or `+aaa+` but not `-aaa+`. In that case, this should work:

```
^([-+]).+\1$
```

This matches `[-+]` for a - or + character (- first so it is not seen as a range), then some characters, then the first group again. The first group is the first character because we put it in brackets.

Example:

```
$ echo '-aaaa-' | grep -P '^([-+]).+\1$'
-aaaa-
```